# Subprocess pipe broken only when running a script

Tags: python, subprocess, broken-pipe

I'm trying to test a small server application using python. The application is working a bit like a remote shell - it takes an input and outputs some data based on the input.

My initial try looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import subprocess

nc = subprocess.Popen(['/usr/bin/ncat','127.0.0.1','9999'], stdin = 
subprocess.PIPE, stdout = subprocess.PIPE)

nc.stdin.write(b'test')
```

This doesn't work and tells me:

```
write: Broken pipe
```

However when i test this out in a python3 interactive intepreter everything seems to be working just fine:

```
$ /usr/bin/python3
Python 3.5.3 (default, Sep 27 2018, 17:25:39) 
[GCC 6.3.0 20170516] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import subprocess
>>> nc = subprocess.Popen(['ncat','127.0.0.1','9999'], stdin = subprocess.PIPE, stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
>>> nc.stdin.write(b'test')
4
```

When I run the ncat in the shell it also waits for the input as expected.

So what is going on? How is the interactive interpreter different from running a script and why does it affect the subprocesses?

---

Some notes:

- I don't want to use sockets myself. The server I'm testing is run via xinetd, which means that the executable can also be tested by running it directly. With the current solution I could change `['/usr/bin/ncat','127.0.0.1','9999']` to `['./server_executable']` and test everything without the networking inbetween. With sockets I'd lose this functionality.
- I know about pexpect and I even consider using it. Even if I end up not using the subprocesses I'd like to know what the heck is happening here.
- When I provide the server executable to Popen everything works fine. This could hint that there is some problem with ncat and how it is run (don't know if it's relevant but I use ncat version 7.40).

Comment: did you try to use [`communicate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate)?

Comment: I have more then one thing to do, and some actions are dependent on an output from previous steps. `comunicate()` doesn't work because it waits for the subprocess to terminate.

Comment: How are you executing the standalone script?

Comment: Is `/usr/bin/ncat` the same as `ncat`?

Comment: I tried `./script.py` and `/usr/bin/python3 script.py`. Neither is working as expected.

Comment: I changed `ncat` to `/usr/bin/ncat` to check if it's some problem with paths, but they are the same executable and only ncat on that system, as far as I know.